# Return records from a table whose key this referenced in another table CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I'm using the **CakePHP 3** native **ORM** to retrieve the records of the product table (by ID) 
along with the records that the reference to the product record with following method:

```
public function view($id) 
{ 
if($this->request->is('get')) 
{ 
$product = $this->Products->get($id, [ 
'contain' => ['Stores', 'Bookings', 'ProductFeatures', 'ProductMedias'] 
]); 
$this->set('product', $product); 

$bannerType = 2; 
$bannersQuantity = 1; 
$fullBanners = $this->Search->listAllBanners($bannerType, $bannersQuantity); 
$this->set('fullBanners', $fullBanners); 

$logged = $this->Auth->user(); 
$this->set('logged', $logged); 

$this->set('pageTitle', $product['product_name'].' - Stores'); 
} 
}
```

This being basically returned all records that need, but how do I return every record in table **features** 
that referenced in **product_features** table ?

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE products ( 
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
store_id INT NOT NULL, 
sub_category_id INT NOT NULL, 
quantity INT NOT NULL, 
sold INT NOT NULL, 
description VARCHAR(1000), 
price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL, 
old_price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL, 
visited INT NOT NULL, 
thumbnail VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
status INT NOT NULL, 
created DATETIME, 
modified DATETIME, 
FOREIGN KEY store_key (store_id) REFERENCES stores(id), 
FOREIGN KEY sub_category_key (sub_category_id) REFERENCES sub_categories(id) 
); 

CREATE TABLE sub_categories ( 
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
sub_category_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
category_id INT NOT NULL, 
created DATETIME, 
modified DATETIME, 
FOREIGN KEY category_key (category_id) REFERENCES categories(id) 
); 

CREATE TABLE features ( 
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
feature_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
created DATETIME, 
modified DATETIME 
); 

CREATE TABLE product_features ( 
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
feature_value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
feature_id INT NOT NULL, 
product_id INT NOT NULL, 
created DATETIME, 
modified DATETIME, 
FOREIGN KEY feature_key (feature_id) REFERENCES features(id), 
FOREIGN KEY product_key (product_id) REFERENCES products(id) 
);
```

**EDIT**

```
public function initialize(array $config) 
{ 
$this->table('products'); 
$this->displayField('id'); 
$this->primaryKey('id'); 
$this->addBehavior('Timestamp'); 
$this->belongsTo('Stores', [ 
'foreignKey' => 'store_id', 
'joinType' => 'INNER' 
]); 
$this->hasMany('Bookings', [ 
'foreignKey' => 'product_id' 
]); 
$this->hasMany('ProductFeatures', [ 
'foreignKey' => 'product_id' 
]); 
$this->hasMany('ProductMedias', [ 
'foreignKey' => 'product_id' 
]); 
}
```

Comment: Have you defined the joins within the Table objects? 

For example in the `initialise()` with the product table you would need something like

    `public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('ProductFeatures');
    }`

Comment: I added the method in question @MattStephens

Comment: Did it make any difference?